# Is there a way to autorun a script?

Tags: python, scripting

I was wondering if I could autorun my script as soon as I opened the blender file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the script from the command prompt or a batch file

```
blender blenderFile.blend --python myscript.py
```

Comment: That code does not work in a command prompt because blender is not a valid command

Comment: Ah sorry, it would only work if the command prompt / batch file was opened in the same folder as blender. 

Otherwise you could specify the whole path like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender"